# AWS API gateway: delete all API keys without id

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have many (10K+) old unused AWS API Gateway API keys. I do not know their key-id. Is there any way i could delete those ? (obviously clicking via AWS console would work but does not make any sense).

AWS CLI like delete-api-key or get-api-key seems to require key-id....

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the solution: aws apigateway get-api-keys